# Use multiprocessing to update cells in google spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, google-docs-api, telethon

I am trying to calculate numbers in parallel and put them into cells in a google spreadsheet. The following is my code:

```
import multiprocessing, ezsheets

ss = ezsheets.Spreadsheet(spreadsheet_url)
sheet2 = ss[1]

def myfunc(inputs):
    a = sum(inputs)
    sheet2['A1']=a
    return

processes = []
for i in range(1,5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunc, args=[[1,2,3]])
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

But it does not change a cell. What am I doing wrong?

I am calling a function that uses `GetHistoryRequest` from telethon. Does that make a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that with multiprocessing each process has its own memory space and therefore sees its own copy of variable `sheet2`.

A secondary issue is that your code is invoking `myfunc` 5 times with the same argument and updating the same cell 5 times with the same value, so this is not a realistic use case. A more realistic example would be where you needed to set 5 different cells invoking `myfunc` with 5 different arguments. The easiest way to solve this would not to have `myfunc` attempt to update a shared spreadsheet but rather to just have it return to the main process the value that needs to be set in the cell and for the main process to do the actual cell setting. And to return a value from a subprocess the easiest way to do this is to use a process pool:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import ezsheets


def myfunc(inputs):
    return sum(inputs)

if __name__ == '__main__': # required for Windows
    ss = ezsheets.Spreadsheet(spreadsheet_url)
    sheet2 = ss[1]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        a1 = executor.submit(myfunc, [1,2,3])
        a2 = executor.submit(myfunc, [4,5,6])
        a3 = executor.submit(myfunc, [7,8,9])
        a4 = executor.submit(myfunc, [8,9,10])
        a5 = executor.submit(myfunc, [11,12,13])
        sheet2['A1'] = a1.result()
        sheet2['A2'] = a2.result()
        sheet2['A3'] = a3.result()
        sheet2['A4'] = a4.result()
        sheet2['A5'] = a5.result()
```